# aks + firewall. How to route eggress trafic via multiple Ip address

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-aks, static-ip-address, kubernetes-service

My basic problem is to run multiple containers that make HTTP requests to a test server. I need the source IP registered by the test server to be different for the request made by each container. I am using azure AKS.
So far I follow the documentation from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/limit-egress-traffic#restrict-egress-traffic-using-azure-firewall
The above works fine. I need to run another container with a different IP address. For that I created a new Ip address to the firewall, a new Kubernetes service, and a new NAT rules connecting them. That didn't work: the source Ip registered by the test server is the same firewall IP.

The Documentation also states that:
"If needed, you can generalize the steps above to forward the traffic to your preferred egress solution, following the Outbound Type userDefinedRoute documentation."

For that, I create a cluster with vm-set-type of VirtualMachineScaleSets and load-balancer-sku of Standard. Try the above steps and it didn't work. Also, I created a new route on the Route table connecting the internet to the new public IP.. nothing
I am lack of ideas. I don't know if I mess something up. Anyway.. Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found this question, which I have just asked a similar question myself for more for VM